# How do make an ACL to allow the searching of contacts in a smart group?

Tags: email, search, acl

I want to allow someone to send email to a group.

So I'm trying to set up an ACL to allow for the searching for contacts in this group.  In the ACL definition dialog I'm choosing the 'search' operation and for type of data, 'a group of contacts'.  But I'm getting an error, "Only 'View' and 'Edit' operations are valid for this type of data."

It seems like this should be possible...but I don't understand the reason behind the error message.

Can anyone shed some light on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'View' operation on the group of contacts. This will restrict the ACL role to search and view only the contacts in the group which you specified.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that.  The users in the group granted this permission get an access denied message using a https:/mycivisite/civicrm/contact/search?reset=1 url.  Or any type of search url.   What should the above ACL specifically grant in the admin ui?

Comment: Is ''CiviCRM: access CiviCRM" drupal permission given for the drupal user's role? This permission will be needed alone with the above configured CiviCRM ACL for the user to search/view contacts in the specified group.

Comment: It looks like this is the direct link that should work for the user in the role.  https://mycivisite.com/civicrm/group/search?reset=1&force=1&context=smog&gid=5   Yes, the user in the role can already mange events.